# Using JGrasp with Java and C Interchangabley

Tags: jgrasp

I use the JGrasp when programming in Java for AP Computer Science for school, but then for a project outside of school I need to be able to also code and create programs in C. Would I have to go into Workspace and change the default language every time I want to switch between which language I'm writing in? I have both JDK and a C language compiler downloaded onto my computer.

Answer (score 0):

The language setting at the workspace (or project) settings level does not change anything except the language for which settings are shown. That is, it affects only the settings dialog and not anything else. Only the file level language setting matters (it determines the language for the corresponding file). Whatever is the the language for the file in focus, that language will be used. You can have Java and C files/projects open at the same time and there will be no conflicts.